# Django/JS: passing a parameter through url from .js file to django view

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to pass a numerical parameter through the url to my class based Django view method `get` within my class `Quit`. How do I go about doing this?

***.js file code...***

```
function restart_or_quit_game(){

    this.quit = function quit(number){
        if(number === 1){
            window.location.href='quit/1';
        }
    }
}
```

***urls.py file...***

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^quit/(?P<id>\d+)$', Quit.as_view()),
    url(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
]
```

***view file***

```
class Quit(View):
    def get(self, request, id):
        print(id)
        return redirect('/')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to import `redirect` with the following code. Everything works gravy now!

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
```